# Spawn platform based on player location

Tags: unity, 2d

I am trying to make an endless platformer game. I have made a lot of progress so far. I now want to be able to change platforms when I take an object(power-up or something). I modified my platform spawner script in order to calculate the players position and use that as the `startPosition` since it will not be spawned in the beginning as the normal platforms. This is what I want http://gfycat.com/GleamingDeadlyGreendarnerdragonfly
and this is what I got so far http://gfycat.com/MeagerEducatedAnchovy
the problem is that it spawns the platforms too late. I am fairly sure that it's because I use `lastposition` to calculate when to spawn the other platforms and I use s`tartSpawnPositionLava`. It's a 2D game btw
Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TerrainSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // terrain references   
    public GameObject jumpTerrain;
    public GameObject climbTerrain;
    public GameObject platformTerrain;
    public GameObject platform1Terrain;
    public GameObject platform2Terrain;
    public GameObject snowTerrain;
    private GameObject playerPos;
    // starting position for terrain, number found from tweaking in the editor
    public float startSpawnPosition = 11.2f;
    private float startSpawnPositionLava = 0;
    // y position that all terrain will be spawned
    // my terrain is all joined at the same level
    // you can change this if here and the spawn method 
    // if you need terrain at different heights
    public int spawnYPos = 0;
    public int spawnYLava = 0;

    private CoinGenerator theCoinGenerator;

    public float _time = 0f;
    // random number that is used for selecting the terrain
    int randomChoice;
    // keep track of the last position terrain was generated
    float lastPosition;
    // camera reference
    GameObject cam;
    // used to check if terrain can be generated depending on the camera position and lastposition
    bool canSpawn = true;

    void Start()
    {
        // make the lastposition start at start spawn position
        lastPosition = startSpawnPosition;
        // pair camera to camera reference
        cam = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        theCoinGenerator = FindObjectOfType<CoinGenerator>();
        playerPos = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");
        var pos = playerPos.transform.position.x;
        startSpawnPositionLava = pos;
        Debug.Log (startSpawnPositionLava);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        // if the camera is farther than the number last position minus 16 terrain is spawned
        // a lesser number may make the terrain 'pop' into the scene too early
        // showing the player the terrain spawning which would be unwanted
        if (cam.transform.position.x >= lastPosition - 25 && canSpawn == true)
        {
            // turn off spawning until ready to spawn again
            canSpawn = false;
            // we choose the random number that will determine what terrain is spawned
            randomChoice = Random.Range(1, 12);
            // SpawnTerrain is called and passed the randomchoice number
            SpawnTerrain(randomChoice);
        }

        _time += Time.deltaTime;
        //Debug.Log (_time);
        if (_time >= 45)
        {
            // Do stuff
            //Reset our timer back to 60
            _time -= 45.0f;
        }
        //Debug.Log(_time);
        /* _time = Time.time;
         Debug.Log (_time);
         if (_time >= 61) {
             _time = 0.0f; 
         }
         */
        Debug.Log (_time);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var pos = playerPos.transform.position.x;
        startSpawnPositionLava = pos;
    }
    // spawn terrain based on the rand int passed by the update method
    void SpawnTerrain(int rand)
    {
        //if (_time <= 15)
        //{
            if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 4)
           {
                Instantiate(jumpTerrain, new Vector3(lastPosition, spawnYPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                // same as start spawn position as starting terrain
                // is the same length as the rest of the terrain prefabs
                lastPosition += 23.045f;
            }

            if (rand >= 5 && rand <= 8)
            {
                Instantiate(climbTerrain, new Vector3(lastPosition, spawnYPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                lastPosition += 23.045f;
            }

            if (rand >= 9 && rand <= 10)
            // the platform terrain is more difficult to traverse
            // so we will lessen the chances of it spawning
            {
                Instantiate(platformTerrain, new Vector3(lastPosition, spawnYPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                lastPosition += 23.045f;
            }
            if (rand >= 10 && rand <= 12)
            {
                Instantiate(platform1Terrain, new Vector3(lastPosition, spawnYPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                lastPosition += 23.045f;
            }


            if (_time >= 15 && _time <= 30) {

            if (rand >= 0 && rand <= 12) {
                //Application.LoadLevel("scene_02");
                Instantiate (platform2Terrain, new Vector3 (startSpawnPositionLava, spawnYLava, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
                startSpawnPositionLava += 23.045f;
            }
        }

            if (_time >= 30 && _time <= 45) {
                if (rand >= 0 && rand <= 12) {
                //Application.LoadLevel("scene_01");
                    Instantiate (snowTerrain, new Vector3 (lastPosition, spawnYPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
                    lastPosition += 23.045f;
                    }
            }
        // script is now ready to spawn more terrain
        canSpawn = true;


        }


    }
```